# can not read property 'then' of undefined in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, apollo-server

In models/index.js file, I am trying to write the database connection

```js
const connectDb = () => {
  if (process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL) {
    return mongoose.connect(
      process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
    );
  }

  if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
    return mongoose.connect(
      process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
    );
  }
};
```

In the main index.js file, I am trying to call the `connectDb()` function like below:-

```js
connectDb().then(async () => {
  if (isTest || isProduction) {
    // reset database
    await Promise.all([
      models.User.deleteMany({}),
      models.Message.deleteMany({}),
    ]);

    createUsersWithMessages(new Date());
  }

  httpServer.listen({ port }, () => {
    console.log(`Apollo Server on http://localhost:${port}/graphql`);
  });
});
```

I am getting the error below like this:-

````
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Gaurav's-Stuff\fullstack-apollo-express-mongodb-boilerplate\src/index.js:95:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Module._compile (D:\Gaurav's-Stuff\fullstack-apollo-express-mongodb-boilerplate\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Gaurav's-Stuff\fullstack-apollo-express-mongodb-boilerplate\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:88:7)        
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Gaurav's-Stuff\fullstack-apollo-express-mongodb-boilerplate\node_modules\@babel\node\lib\_babel-node.js:224:23)   
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)```
````

Comment: your  ```const connectDb = () => {``` is not async and is not returning any promise, you will have to resolve it in the connectDb function, ```.then``` catches the promise, hence you getting error

Comment: @Coderboi, I am not able to understand, how I can do this, can you please give any example??

Comment: which version of mongoose you are using ?

Comment: @Coderboi I am using mongoose version:- "^5.8.3"

Comment: check your process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL and process.env.DATABASE_URL

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

from this line of code:

```
connectDb().then(async () => {
```

Then, that means that `connectDb()` is returning `undefined` rather than returning a promise.

Looking at that code:

```
const connectDb = () => {
  if (process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL) {
    return mongoose.connect(
      process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
    );
  }

  if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
    return mongoose.connect(
      process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
    );
  }
};
```

We know that in the version of mongoose you said you have, `mongoose.connect()` already returns a promise so the only way `connectDb()` could not be returning a promise is if both your `if` statements evaluated to false, if neither `process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL` or `process.env.DATABASE_URL` had a value or if `mongoose.connect()` isn't actually returning a promise (you somehow have an older version of mongoose installed).

One simple way to verify the environment variables is to just add a couple log statements:

```
const connectDb = () => {
  if (process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL) {
    console.log("Found TEST_DATABASE_URL");
    return mongoose.connect(
      process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
    );
  }

  if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
    console.log("Found DATABASE_URL");
    return mongoose.connect(
      process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
    );
  }

  console.log("Never supposed to get here")
  throw new Error("Need either TEST_DATABASE_URL OR DATABASE_URL set in the environment");
};
```

---

FYI, there are lots of places in your code where you are not doing proper error detection or handling, starting with the db connection and also in your second code block.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
const connectDb = async () => {
  let x = null;
  if (process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL) {
    x = await mongoose.connect(
      process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
    );
  }

  if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
    x = await mongoose.connect(
      process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      { useNewUrlParser: true },
    );
  }
  if(x){ return Promise.resolve(db) } else { return Promise.reject("reject"); }

};
```

Comment: What does this fix?  If `mongoose.connect()` returns a promise (which you seem to be thinking it does since you're using `await` with it), then the OP's code would have similarly worked just fine as the OP was already returning that.  Both the OP's code and your code have issues if neither one of the `if` statements evaluates to `true`.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-yxe3f6?embed=1&view=editor

connectDb () wont work without async tag , ```.then(() => ())``` need async function, i was giving him idea what's going on , so i didn't return .connect directly

Comment: @jfriend00 what's ur opinion

Comment: This simply adds extra code without doing anything useful. The real bug is that there is no `else` in your `if (x)` or that there is not case handling if both `if` is false in the OP's code. Consider your own code: `if (x) { return a promise } // else return undefined`